# Как обновить ListView в Ormlite?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, listview

Как обновить `ListView` при удалении данных?

Я использую [Ormlite](http://ormlite.com/) и `Adapter` наследуется от `BaseAdapter`. Функция для обновления списка `notifyDataSetChanged()` не работает. Обновлять активити не удобно.

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос [на англ.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650869/android-ormlite-refresh-list-on-delete)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас есть в классе адаптера переменная, в коей хранится список данных. Если так, то после удаления данных вам надо удалить их и из адаптера, а потом его уже обновлять, вызывая **notifyDataSetChanged()**.

> *Если же вы делаете как-то не так, то добавьте код в вопрос. В нынешнем виде сказать что-то более определённое сложно.*